# Can I inject custom view components into a Vue.js grid component?

Tags: components, decorator, vue.js

I have a data grid component in Vue.js, which looks a bit like the one in the official sample: http://vuejs.org/examples/grid-component.html

Based on the input data instead of pure strings sometimes I'd like to display entries "decorated" as a checkbox or a v-link component (not exclusively, I may need to render other components too, like unescaped HTML or an img).

Obviously I don't want to prepare the Grid component for all the use cases, so this is *not* what I'd like to do:

*A sample data model to be displayed:*

```
model = [
  {
    field1: 'some string',
    field2: 'another string',
    field3: { // this should be a checkbox
      state: true
    },
    field4: { // this should be an <a v-link>
      url: 'http://whatever',
      label: 'go somewhere'
    }
  }
]
```

*A relevant excerpt from the Grid component:*

```
<template>
  ...
    <tr v-for="entry in model">
      <td>
        <div v-if="typeof entry === 'object' && entry.hasOwnPropery('url')">
          <a v-link="entry.url">{{ entry.label }}</a>
        </div>
        <div v-if="typeof entry === 'object' && entry.hasOwnProperty('state')">
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="entry.state">
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          {{ entry }}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ...
</template>
```

What's the Vue.js philosophy for injecting custom components as decorators? I want my Grid to be completely agnostic regarding these decorator components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good place for a mutable component piece. You define a few different decorator components and then use your data to decide which one should be used for rendering.

Template:

```
<div id="app">
<ul>
    <li
    v-for="entry in entries"
    >
    <component :is="entry.type">
        {{ entry.content }}
    </component>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'blank': {
      template: '<div><slot></slot></div>'
    },
    'green': {
      template: '<div style="color: #0f0;"><slot></slot></div>'
    },
    'red': {
      template: '<div style="background-color: #f00;"><slot></slot></div>'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    entries: function() {
      return this.raw_entries.map(
        function(entry) {
          if (typeof entry !== "object") {
            return { type: 'blank', content: entry }
          }

          if (!entry.hasOwnProperty('type')) {
            entry.type = 'blank'
          }

          return entry
        }
      )
    }
  },
  data: {
    raw_entries: [
      'Base Text',
      {
        type: 'green',
        content: 'Green Text'
      },
      {
        type: 'red',
        content: 'Red Background'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4km8r85r/1/) Working example using lists